# Understanding Battery rating

Tags: batteries, battery-operated, battery-chemistry

I need clarification regarding the rating of the battery shown in the below figure. I know battery ratings are given in Ah(Ampere-hour), but here it is given A/s. The picture is from "Linden's handbook of batteries" section on Thermal Batteries(Page No:21.14). So, what does 3400-A/s tells us?

[image]

Comment: What does the reference \$From Street^{19}\$ point to?

Comment: It points to "Characteristics and Development Report of the MC3573 Thermal Battery" SAND82-0695,1983. But I couldn't find the whole document to study, just its abstract is available.

Comment: Funny, a search for "SAND82-0695" gives this question as the top result.  After 31 years, you're the only one talking about this paper in a searchable-text format.

Answer (score 1):

That "3400-A/s" may be the model number or serial number of a particular research cell which is being described.  I looked through that section of the Linden book and 3400-A/s isn't mentioned again in the text.  The author borrowed a table from a research paper to use as a "representative example" of an Li(Si)/FeS2 cell.

The way the caption is worded doesn't seem to mean they are giving a technical spec in amps per second.  If they were, there wouldn't be a dash between 3400 and A/s.  Amps per second wouldn't make sense to talk about in most cases, as it represents coulombs per second squared, the "acceleration" of charge rather than "velocity."  Like slew rate for current.